# Openstack heat template default user

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

Can I somehow set the default user in openstack heat template? This is possible on any cloud provider but I did not found it in the heat template docs. Default username means the login user to the instance.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new user, or specify the default user that is configured on the image itself? If you are trying to create a user then userdata + cloud-init may be the way to go. https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/template_guide/software_deployment.html. http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html